# Vue render element with directive

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to render this directive using Render Function

```
<h2 v-tooltip.top="{ content: 'You have new messages.', classes: 'tooltip-info', offset: 15 }">
            some text
</h2>
```

Using this code inside function

```
return createElement('h2', {
                    directives: [
                        {
                            name: 'v-tooltip',
                            value: {
                                content: field.tooltip.content ? field.tooltip.content : field.tooltip,
                                classes: field.tooltip.class ? field.tooltip.class : 'tooltip-info',
                                offset: 15,
                            },
                            arg: 'top',
                        },
                    ],
                }, [field.title]);
```

but i get this error:
[`Vue warn]: Failed to resolve directive: v-tooltip`

Am i missing something, field is object which might have content or class prop.
So i set them if it has or go to default in the else.

v-tooltip is this directive https://github.com/Akryum/v-tooltip

Comment: name should be just `tooltip` if I am not mistaken

Comment: jesus thank you! answer it so i can accept the answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, `v-tooltip` should be changed to `tooltip`.

When defining a directive in vuejs, the name does not need the `v-` prefix: example:

```
Vue.directive('focus', {
  inserted: function (el) {
    el.focus()
  }
})
```

the above directive can be then called as:

```
<input v-focus>
```

<sub>[source](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/custom-directive.html)</sub>

Comment: How can we pass the options? Such as `v-tooltip.bottom` to place the tooltip on the bottom

Comment: @null Args should be used as `v-my-directive:foo` and accessed via second param of `inserted`, as follows: `inserted: function (el, binding) { console.log(binding.arg) }`